# Exchanging seamlessly between Fixed and Relative position

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm developing a page where during the scroll, elements, at **breakpoints**, will **stop  on the screen** and animate, once the final point in the scroll is reached they go back to normal scrolling page behavior.

Basically, once div X gets to the middle of the screen it position changes to **fixed**, and will stop at middle of the screen expanding, moving etc, as the user scrolls, and reached the final scroll point, it will stop and change from position fixed to **relative** *staying in the same spot*.

I did a prototype where once the element got to the point on the screen I wanted it to start animate, i would measure its position on the screen with the browser ruler and get the fixed position it should take from then on.

BUT this is a poor and ugly solution, with a lot of hand work.

We can get the scroll and sum up things to get the Y position, but the x position messes up for making the design responsive.

How to do with JS This change?
How to get the ***Fixed** equivalent position of a **Relative** element dynamically?*

I dont have much experience with JS, but I'm sure there are good solutions for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question... But just learned about `position:sticky`,
this seems to resolve the problem with just CSS, very easy and way more smooth.

```css
#wrap{
    margin:15px;
    padding:10px;
}


.d1{
    
    width:400px;
    height:500px;
}


#d2{
    //background-color:red;
    height:900px;
}


#d3{
  width:100px;
    height:50px;
    border: 10px solid black;
    background-color:green;
    position: sticky;
    top: 70px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    
<div id="wrap">
    <div class="d1"><div>Scroll Down</div></div>

    <div id="d2" >
        <div id="d3" class="content">I'm the guy...</div>
    </div>

    <div  class="d1"><div>
  <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
  <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
  Scroll Up</div></div>

</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that IS the solution, to use js for changing instantaneously the position (x,y) and the position (absolute/fixed). Also I think there's a library for that but here's a sketch of a solution.

```js
var div = document.querySelector(".dog");
var div_status = document.querySelector("#div_status");
var start = 100;
var stop = 800;
var swap = false;
window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
  var y = window.scrollY
  var rect = div.getBoundingClientRect();
  div_status.innerText = rect.top.toFixed() + " " + y.toFixed()
  if (y >= start && y <= stop) {

    div_status.style.background = "green"
    if (!swap) {
      div.style.position = "fixed";

      div.style.top = rect.top + "px"
      swap = true
    }
  } else {
    div_status.style.background = "red"
    if (swap) {

      div.style.position = "absolute";
      div.style.top = (y + rect.top) + "px"
      swap = false;
    }

  }
})
```

```css
body {
  height: 2000px;
}

.dog {
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  background: lightyellow;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

#div_status {
  background: red;
  color: white;
  position: fixed;
  right: 100px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <pre id="div_status">0 0</pre>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br> keep scrolling
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div class="dog">Dog</div>

</body>
```

Comment: There is this comment from the firefox on listening to scroll, a snap function may be needed too, some animations of mine got janky:
https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/performance/scroll-linked_effects.html